# What's the easiest way to wrap a big JSON from array of objects to an object with "data" in typeScript

Tags: json, typescript

What's the easiest way to wrap a big JSON from array of objects to an object with "data" in typeScript:

**From this:**

```
[
   {
      "label":"testing",
      "id":1,
      "children":[
         {
            "label":"Preamble",
            "id":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**To this:**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "label":"testing",
         "id":1,
         "children":[
            {
               "label":"Preamble",
               "id":2
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see the only difference is the { "data": ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
let resultArray =
{
    "data": [
        ...sourceArray
    ]
}
```

Note: This question fits rather in the "JavaScript" category than "TypeScript"